# How should I solve this differential equation with f(x) not given?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I mean I cannot evaluate the particular integral since f(x) is not known. And how do I come up with double integral formula shown above?

Comment: It's multiple choice, just plug the guess into the ode and see if it's actually a solution.

Comment: Yes I know we can solve by doing that. But what about an actual hardcore maths solution?

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: What are the roots of the characteristic equation?

Comment: @LutzL-the roots of the characteristic equation is 1,1 since (D-1)²=0

Comment: Ahmed S-Plugging in is really not a good option. Just try it for yourself

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} - 2 \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + y = \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} - \operatorname{id} \right)^2 y.$$

So first we solve the equation

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} - y = f(x).$$

For that we multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$ and contract

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot e^{-x} - y e^{-x} & = e^{-x} f(x) \\ 
\left( y e^{-x} \right)' & = e^{-x} f(x) \\
y e^{-x} & = \int e^{-x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \\
y & = e^x \int e^{-x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
\end{align*}
$$

We denote the solution by $y_1$. Now by the observation in the beginning, we have

$$\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} - \operatorname{id} \right)\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} - \operatorname{id} \right) y = f(x)$$

hence

$$\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} - \operatorname{id} \right) y = y_1$$

which we solve in the same way, obtaining

$$y = e^x \int e^{-x} y_1 \, \mathrm{d} x.$$

Substituting $y_1$ yields

$$y = e^x \int e^{-x} \left[ e^x \int e^{-x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \right] \, \mathrm{d} x = e^x \iint e^{-x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x.$$

Comment: Wow, serious brilliance

Comment: +1 Elegant solution and definitely one the multiple choice was hinting at. I wish they'd taught me this in Diff-Eq

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)

The homogeneous equation

$$ y'' - 2y' + y = 0 $$

has solutions $y_1 = e^x$, $y_2 = xe^x$

Let the particular solution have the form
$$ y_p(x) = v_1(x)e^x + v_2(x)xe^x $$

Applying the [general method for second order equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second_order_equation) we can impose the conditions

$$ {v_1}'e^x + {v_2}'xe^x = 0 $$
$$ {v_1}'e^x + {v_2}'(e^x + xe^x) = f(x) $$

Solving this gives
$$ {v_1}' = -xe^{-x}f(x) $$
$$ {v_2}' = e^{-x}f(x) $$

So the particular solution is 
$$ y_p = -e^x\int xe^{-x}f(x)dx + xe^x\int e^{-x}f(x) dx $$

You can use integration by parts to prove

$$ \int xe^{-x}f(x) dx = x \int e^{-x}f(x) - \int\int e^{-x}f(x) dxdx $$

Which gives the final form
$$ y_p = e^x \int\int e^{-x} f(x)dxdx$$

Comment: I just remembered about the method of parameters technique :)